# I'm trying to select two columns as one column in MySQL but output is not coming

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to use the concatenation operator( || ) to select two columns as one in MySQL. But, the output is not coming.

The table 'emp' has four columns named -> eid (int), fname (varchar(20)), lname (varchar(20)) and salary (float).

3 records are entered into the table emp.

Now, when I'm trying to execute the following query:

```
SELECT fname || lname as Name from emp;
```

The result is coming out to be:

Name
0
0
0

instead of the names like "John Doe", etc.

Comment: Do not use || to concatenate values.  Use something like concat(fname, ' ', lname) instead.  The || is used for logical OR operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `CONCAT()` function

```
SELECT concat(fname, ' ', lname) as Name from emp;
```

In MySQL the `||` is a logical OR, hence the result you are getting